# Prove that the least upper bound property cannot be derived from the nested interval property without the archimedean property.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

Show that the least upper bound property cannot be proven from the nested interval property without the archimedean property.

I am curious as to how one could prove statements that have the same logical structure to the above.  Moreover, can anyone prove the above?

Comment: The most common approach is to find a model of the axioms that satisfies the proposed premise but not the conclusion. What _exactly_ is it you call the "nested interval property", though? In particular, does it quantify over naturals other than as indices?

Comment: @HenningMakholm http://personal.bgsu.edu/~carother/cantor/Nested.html ,  sorry is there something similarly named?  Can you explain what you mean by reference to my example question?

Comment: Hmm, that looks rather subtle. Without knowing _exactly_ what all the other axioms being assumed are, I can't be sure what the setter of the exercise intended. I suspect the key point may be that you need the Archimedean property to show that there is any sequence of positive numbers that converges to $0$ at all. (But I may be overlooking something, because a counterexample based on that observation would require some transfinite set theory that usually cannot be assumed known in an elementary real analysis course).

Comment: Did the instructor give you any examples of non-Archimedean fields?  Probably a counterexample was already in one of the lectures.  I doubt it the instructor would expect you to come up with a new example from scratch.